# Is there an equivalent to Airfoil available for Linux?

Tags: linux, macos, audio

I just stumbled across this Airfoil on Mac OS X, which lets me 'throw' music from my laptop to any other linux machine, iPhone or other device hooked up to a better set of speakers than my laptop - here's the page below:

http://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/mac/

What tools would I use to recreate this functionality on a linux box - are there any nice GUI interfaces to something like pulse audio (which is what I imagine I'd use ) for doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

See [YoLinux: Linux Audio Streaming](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialAudioStreaming.html) as one option.
This also might be useful: [Streaming audio on GNU/Linux - the miniest HOWTO](http://www.linux.ie/articles/streamingaudio.php).

Airfoil Speakers for Linux is [here](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/linux/speakers.php), but this is only a small part of an answer.

From [Anything like Airfoil (audio stream util) that can run on Ubuntu](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/anything-like-airfoil-audio-stream-util-that-can-run-on-ubuntu-684445/):

> I use [raop-play](http://raop-play.sourceforge.net/).
>
> I mainly run debian unstable and got
>   it work on my laptop with ubuntu junky
>   ;-) as well ... I run the stand-alone
>   client raop_play, not the alsa device.
>
> I got the sound device to compile with
>   my kernel, however, I never got the
>   alsa sound device to work ... programs
>   complain it is no alsa sound device
>   ...
>
> So what I do is the following:
>
> ```
> mkfifo ~/sound.wav
> raop_play airport_express_ip ~/sound.wav &
> in vlc I set output to the file: ~/sound.wav
> ```
>
> Everything I play through vlc now
>   plays on the speakers ... I have to
>   restart both vlc or raop_play about
>   every 5 hours or so, because one of
>   them seems to have a problem after
>   some time (raop disconnects or vlc
>   hangs) ... not really a big issue,
>   though ... I use it all day long every
>   workday ... ;-)
>
> It is more reliable than iTunes, which
>   just stops sending the audio to the
>   airtunes every 5 to 10 songs ... I
>   think my airtunes maybe to blame, but
>   raop manages much longer connections

Comment: Will this keep the various playbacks in sync?  What's the latency like?